# Ubuntu 16.04 Server console Dark

Tags: console

I have a home sever running Ubuntu server 14.04 with an attached monitor and keyboard that was working fine. I upgraded to Ubuntu server 16.04 and now the monitor is fine during the BIOS boot phase of startup but then goes dark and I can not access my server from the monitor and keyboard while Ubuntu is running. I am able to ssh in to the server to perform operations but not from the attached monitor and keyboard. Something changed but what?  - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that responded. I typed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and the console monitor and keyboard came on.  Thanks again